# Is there a way to move a jMenuBar to somewhere else than the top of my jFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating an undecorated jFrame, and I wanted to add a jMenuBar to this jFrame to allow me to use drop-down menus for various things.

But, the jMenuBar always defaults to the very top of my jFrame, and it being undecorated, it pushes down a jPanel I had set there with the "Minimize" and "Close" buttons, and trying to move it anywhere else is unsuccessful.

I've tried using a jToolBar, and while it allows for more customization in terms of placement, I can't find a way to add drop-down menus onto the buttons there.

Is there a way to move a jMenuBar somewhere else than the top or to add a drop-down menu to a jToolBar?

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Here is a simple example to achieve what you want, using a `BorderLayout`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();

    JPanel container = new JPanel();
    container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JLabel label = new JLabel("North");
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    JMenu menu = new JMenu("A south menu");
    menu.add(new JMenuItem("A south item"));

    menuBar.add(menu);

    container.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    container.add(menuBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    jf.add(container);
    jf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,100));
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.pack();
}
```

result:

[image]